# Sort string items in a datatable as int using c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have some numeric codes stored in a DataTable. When I try to sort it using DataView it sorts the column by string. What is the easiest way to sort the data as integer/number?

```
DataView view = dt.DefaultView();
view.Sort = "Code asc";
dt = view.ToTable();
```

Data in datatable:
128, 123, 112, 12, 126

after sort it shows:
112, 12, 123, 126, 128

expected result:
12, 112, 123, 126, 128

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is working example. You can create another DataTable via Clone, and change the data type of the column to Int and copy the data.

```
    DataTable dt = GetTable(); // Assume this method returns the datatable from service      
    DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();
    dt2.Columns["Code"].DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dt2.ImportRow(dr);
    }
    dt2.AcceptChanges();
    DataView dv = dt2.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "Code ASC";
```

Comment: what will happen if code is "001", will datatype changing from string to integer omit the leading zeros?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to add a Calculated column with the right type and sort on it.

Like this:

```
dt.Columns.Add( "Int32_Code", typeof( int ), "Code" );
dt.DefaultView.Sort("Int32_Code");
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a column in data table, define it as typeof(int)

```
dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
```

Comment: Hmm, in my code I am calling the webservice that returns me the datatable and I simply do `DataTable dt = soaRequest.GetMasterList();`.

Comment: try this
dt.Columns["Code"].DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");

Answer (score 0):

create a new column in datatable as given below and sort on new column code_int
Dt.Columns.Add("Code_int", typeof(Int16), "Convert(Code, 'System.String')");

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider reading other people's answers, before posting your own. Your answer has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661830/6670491).