# Sorting the DataTable is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sorting, datatable

I have one DataTable called "DTStage". It has two columns such as "SeqNbr" and "StageID".

I want to sort the datatable based on "SeqNbr".

The DataTable has the following records:

```
     SeqNbr         StageID
    --------      -----------
       0               1
       1               2
       2               3
       3               4
       4               5
       5               6
       6               7
       7               8
       8               9
       9               10
       10              11
       11              12
       12              13
       13              14
       14              15
       15              16
       16              17
       18              18
       17              19
```

I have used two methods to sort this datatable, they are as follows:

```
 DTStage = new DataView(DTStage, "", "SeqNbr asc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();

                     &

 DataView dv = DTStage.DefaultView;
 dv.Sort = DTStage.Columns["SeqNbr"] + " asc";
 DTStage = dv.ToTable();
```

But both gives the same result as follows:

```
     SeqNbr         StageID
    --------      -----------
        0               1
        1               2
       10               11
       11               12
       12               13
       13               14
       14               15
       15               16
       16               17
       17               19
       18               18
        2               3
        3               4
        4               5
        5               6
        6               7
        7               8
        8               9
        9               10
```

Why this is not working properly? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like your SeqNbr column is of type string so it gets sorted by characters and not as numbers. if those are numbers (I assume integers) why don't you have the column type as int in the DataTable?

This should help you: [Sort string items in a datatable as int using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Its a natural sorting(string compare). You need to tell dataTable that those are integers.

Comment: Here is same question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `DTStage = dv.ToTable();` please use `DTStage = dv.Table;`

else you will need make the column your sorting as number type on your Sql Table

Answer (score 0):

You should delcare your datatable as

```
Datatable DTStage = new Datatable();

DTStage.Columns.Add("SeqNbr", typeof(int));
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's comparing strings. Try converting them to int.