# sorting a dataView in asc doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dataview

I have a datatable `allImages` containing 2 columns ID and Value. Id may not always be unique in this case as this holds the Id of the record in the original table to which the image is assigned. Being 2 records with Id 10. Means this record has 2 different images attached to it.:

```
Id   Image
3    oop
1    plo
4    uuu
10   plo
10   iko
...and so on..
```

Im converting the DT to a DV to sort in ascending like so:

```
DataView dv = allImages.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "Id asc";
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
```

this returns:

```
 Id   Value
    1    www
    10   plo
    10   iko
    2    was
    3    oop
    4    uuu
```

So it does actually sort them into ascending but only by the first char. How can I get it to sort ASC properly?

Thanks for any help offered

Comment: What's the type of Id ? You have a "string" ordering, not a numeric one.

Comment: order by int instead of string. i dont know how DV works though but try look into it.

Comment: Maybe look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp

Comment: ahh got it now. ordering as string. Yes need to convert it to int thanks guys