# datatable sorting behavior (double values aren't treated as number)

Tags: wpf, sorting, gridview, datatable

I have a field named price in one of the tables in my database and its type is `varchar`. In my window I have a `listview` and a `gridview` in it that is bound to that table. I have set the `GridViewColumnHeader_Click` event of the `gridview` as following:

```
private void GridViewColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "price ASC";
    datatable.DefaultView.ToTable();
}
```

It sorts the price column, but it treats price values as `string`s, so it sorts the prices as `string`s, not numbers. This behavior is expected, because the type of price field was `varchar`. To solve this problem I converted prices into `double` as following:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price, Converter={StaticResource convert1}}" />
```

and:

```
public class dataConvert1 : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { return new object(); }
}
```

But this doesn't solved the problem and prices are still treated as `string`s not `double`s.
This question maybe looks duplicated. But none of the same questions have been answered (here or in any other websites), and this question is still a problem. Please help solve this problem. (please don't suggest to change the type of the field price from `varchar` to `int`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a converter in the view won't affect how the `DataView` of the `DataTable` gets sorted...the converter is just a UI formatting thing so this won't work.

You should really change the type of the column. Or you could add another column to the `DataTable` and sort by this one. Something like this:

```
private void GridViewColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!datatable.Columns.Contains("price2"))
    {
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("price2") { DataType = typeof(double) });
        foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
        {
            dr["price2"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["price"]);
        }
    }
    datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "price2 ASC";
    datatable.DefaultView.ToTable();
}
```

Or you could simply create a copy of the `DataTable` with the appropriate column type and use this one instead of the original `DataTable`:

[Sort string items in a datatable as int using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp)

Comment: This is the answer to the question. I came up to this solution a few minutes ago, and I wanted to write the answer, but fortunately saw that you've done the task, thank you @mm8.